# Complex regex in Apache rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create the following behavior with a rewrite rule.

```
https://domain.com/admin/user/add      => /addedit.php?add=
https://domain.com/admin/user/add/     => /addedit.php?add=
https://domain.com/admin/user/add/123  => /addedit.php?add=123
https://domain.com/admin/user/add/123/ => /addedit.php?add=123
```

- `user` is variable
- `add` can either be "add" or "edit"
- Trailing slashes are always allowed
- There can be more after the slash after (add|edit) which is assigned to the variable

I'm fine up until the optional slash after the action word (add|edit). That's where I don't know regex well enough to accomplish my goal.

Something like the following works:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(add|edit)(/(.*)/?)?$ /admin/$1/addedit.php?$2=$3
```

However, the URLs end up containing the slashes in the `GET` variable. I figured I would be able to reference the `(.*)` in middle of `(/(.*)/?)?` as `$4`, but I am not.

I then read about [non capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and so added a `?:` like so:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(add|edit)(?:/(.*)/?)?$ /admin/$1/addedit.php?$2=$3
```

It's probably a relatively simple thing I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just minor modifications needed:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/(add|edit)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ /admin/$1/addedit.php?$2=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was close. I'm assuming the problem was the fact that `.*` is greedy, as @hjpotter92 said.

Comment: Even `RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(add|edit)(?:/([^/]*))?/?$ /admin/$1/addedit.php?$2=$3 [L,NC]` would have worked. You just needed `[^/]*` inside optional matching group.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match: `^(.*\/admin)(\/user)\/((?:add)|(?:edit))\/?(([^/]*)?\/?)$`

Regex to replace: `/addedit.php?$3=$5`

http://regexr.com?36gp3